# How to use environment variables in prisma

Tags: graphql, environment-variables, prisma

From this [document](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1333), Prisma cli try to download binaries from prisma s3. But as my corporate firewall rules this download was blocked, Following this [document](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/environment-variables-reference),I must change source binary file location by using `PRISMA_ENGINES_MIRROR` variable.

to utilize this variable,I must set environment variables. my build environment is like ElasticBeanstalk,after git push, build will start. from now on,I couldn't configure env variables in build environment. so that I consider to configure and write `PRISMA_ENGINES_MIRROR` variable to `.env` files and push them.

Is it possible? and how can I utilize these variable by `.env` ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure environment variables in Elastic BeanStalk by going to

Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties

You can add `PRISMA_ENGINES_MIRROR` in Environment Properties and it will be picked up by `.env`

[image: EBS Env]